# Checking if a thread is still running using the POSIX thread library on mac osx

Tags: c, macos, pthreads

pthread_quit doesn't seem to be implemented on MACOSX so now im looking for a alternative method to test if a thread is still running, is there any simple method to do this?

currently

```
void GarbageCollector() { 
    while(true) {
        list_t* dummy=takenThreads;
        while(dummy->next!=NULL) {
            if(pthread_kill(dummy->next->value,0)!=0) {
                AddToEnd(RemoveNextFromList(dummy),freeThreads);
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "THREAD DELETED\n");
                continue;
            }
            dummy=dummy->next;
        }
    }
}
```

from the above code i'm calling pthread_kill with a value of 0 to see if a thread is still running, if not I move it from takenThreads to the freeThread pool.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you need this functionality using pthreads, you will have to somehow implement the tracking yourself.